# How do i make my Function output 1 variable?

Tags: matlab

I have been asked to calculate the area of a pyramid using MATLAB. (I am very new to MATLAB).
Below is the function I have written. It gives me the correct answers when I input the values, however It tells me that my code is incorrect because "my function should only have 1 output variable." I am very confused what this means.

```matlab
function CalculatePyramidVolume(baseLength, baseWidth, baseHeight)

   % Function inputs: baseLength, baseWidth, and pyramidHeight
   % Function output: pyramidVolume

   pyramidVolume = baseLength * baseWidth * baseHeight * 1/3
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven’t defined the output. You would just need to revise the first line to:

```
function pyramidVolume = CalculatePyramidVolume(baseLength, baseWidth, baseHeight)
```

This basically tells Matlab to use the value assigned to `pyramidVolume` as the output returned from the function.